# how to select multiple rows as a group based on a column condition in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can we select all the rows in different matching groups based on a column condition

**Data:**

```
**A B   C   D** 

101 1   1   FALSE

101 1   2   FALSE

101 1   3   FALSE

101 2   1   FALSE

101 2   2   FALSE

101 2   3   FALSE

101 2   4   TRUE

102 1   1   FALSE

102 1   2   FALSE

102 1   3   FALSE

102 2   1   FALSE

102 2   2   FALSE

102 2   3   TRUE
```

**Expected Output:**

```
**A B   C   D**

101 2   1   FALSE

101 2   2   FALSE

101 2   3   FALSE

101 2   4   TRUE

102 2   1   FALSE

102 2   2   FALSE

102 2   3   TRUE
```

I need all the rows where B = (B when D = True)

```
df.loc[df.groupby(["A"])[df_rvtlt['D'] == True]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)+[`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).filter(lambda s: s['D'].any())
```

---

```
    A   B   C   D
3   101 2   1   False
4   101 2   2   False
5   101 2   3   False
6   101 2   4   True
10  102 2   1   False
11  102 2   2   False
12  102 2   3   True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One quick question, how to get the same result when there are different values instead of true or false in column D? ```df.groupby(['A', 'B']).filter(lambda s: s['D'] == 'apple') ``` I am getting "filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool" error

Comment: @Cks It depends. You just gotta change the condition inside the lambda function. For example, if you wanna filter based on having at least one value `'some_value'` in column `D`, you write `(s['D']=='some_value').any()`

Comment: @Cks gotta look at the `any()` at the end ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way from `transform`

```
df[df.groupby(['A','B']).D.transform('mean')>0]
Out[256]: 
      A  B  C      D
3   101  2  1  False
4   101  2  2  False
5   101  2  3  False
6   101  2  4   True
10  102  2  1  False
11  102  2  2  False
12  102  2  3   True
```

using `any`

```
df[df.groupby(['A','B']).D.transform('any')]
```

Comment: @rafaelc from the speed up side yes, since any will stop when it find the True , will update